# rails ajax request doesn't refresh data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, refresh

i have some troubles with my ajax request in a rails app.

i make a request, i take some params from a link when i click, and then i want to refresh my partial that contains images from my database.

here is my ajax

```
    $.ajax({

        url:"gallery",
        data: { pie :categoria},
        type: "GET",
        async: true,
        dataType: "script"


    });
```

the thing is that in the rails shell i get passed on my params.
but it doesnt make any changes to the view.

---

my shell:

```
Started GET "/gallery?pie=VibPellizcables&_=1375047201412" for 127.0.0.1 at Sun Jul 28 18:33:21 -0300 2013
Processing by GalleryController#pro as JS
  Parameters: {"pie"=>"VibPellizcables", "_"=>"1375047201412"}
  Product Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `products`.* FROM `products` WHERE `products`.`pie` = 'VibPellizcables'
  Rendered sexytoys/_algo.html.haml (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1ms (Views: 0.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)
```

---

i want to update a partial which contains images from my database.

this is the partial i want to update.

```
  #miniDiv 

    %ul#miniRecuadro
      - @products.each do |product|
        %li.mini= image_tag product.pic.url(:thumb)
```

my controller:

```
      def gallery
        @products = Product.find(:all, :conditions => {:pie => params[:pie]})
        #render :partial => "algo"
        flash[:notice] = "Mensaje ENVIADO >>"
        respond_to do |format|

          format.js {render :partial => 'algo', :conditions => {:pie => params[:pie]}}
         # format.json { render :json => @products  }
        end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do that replacement either in response or AJAX callback:

## Response doing replacement

You need to render a JS file:

```
# app/controllers/gallery_controller.rb
def pro
  ...
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js # no render here
  end
  ...
end

# app/views/gallery/pro.js.erb
$('#your-container').html('<%= j( render partial: 'algo' )%>')
```

I am not sure about this path, application will complain if this path is wrong, you will see this in browser console as this is AJAX. I don't know about `conditions` option is supported in view either.

## Callback doing replacement

```
$.ajax({

    url:"gallery",
    data: { pie :categoria},
    type: "GET",
    async: true,
    success: function(response){
      $('#your-container').html(response);
    }


});
```

Note I removed `dataType: 'script'` here, since you don't want to execute server response.

In this case, you could respond with that html you are responding:

```
# gallery_controller.rb
...
  format.html {render :partial => 'algo', :conditions => {:pie => params[:pie]}}
...
```

Note I changed format of your response since you are rendering html.

## Shortcut

Lastly, if you want to load content from your server inside a container in your page you could be interested in [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
$('#your-container').load('gallery', { pie: categoria });
```

Comment: I try with "Callback doing replacement" option and worked great for me, thanks very much. I'll try later with the other options
Thank you again Juan